# Doubt about minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Given $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix. Called $\psi(\lambda)$ the minimal polynomial of A. If the degree of  $\psi$ is strictly less than the degree of the characteristic polynomial then there exist two polynomials $q,r$, such that: $$ (1+ \lambda)^{n-1} = q(\lambda)\psi(\lambda) + r(\lambda) $$
where the degree of $r$ is strictly less than the degree of the minimal polynomial.
I've found this statement in a proof I'm reading. I've read something about minimal polynomials but I can't understand how this equation jumps out.

Comment: Isn't this just a usual [division of polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition)? Given *any* polynomial $f$, if we divide it by *any* non-constant polynomial $\psi$, the remainder $r$ has degree $<\deg\psi$. In your example the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$. Therefore, $\deg r<\deg\psi<n$, i.e. $\deg r$ is actually strictly less than $n-1$.

Comment: this is a well-known theorem about division of polynomials

Comment: @user1551 Yes I edited it. Yes  I know it is the polynomial division. For some reason I was focusing on the first member, but why do I need that "the degree of ψ is strictly less than the degree of the characteristic polynomial" ?

Comment: @Peanojr You don't need that. Perhaps it was a typo and the authors want $\deg r<n-1$ rather than $\deg r<n$.

Comment: @Peanojr You need it if you want $q\not\equiv 0$. If the degree of $\psi$ was $n,$ then you would get $q\equiv 0$ and $r(\lambda)=(1+\lambda)^{n-1}$ which is probably something the author wants to avoid.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier No, actually $r(\lambda) = (1+\lambda)^{n-1}$ is exactly what the author wants. He wants to show that if $A$ is irreducible then $\forall i,j$ there exists $k(i,j)$ s.t. $ a_{ij}^{(k)} > 0$ with $k$ < degree of $\psi$. If $A$ is irreducible then $0<<(I+A)^{n-1} = r(A) = \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} c_kA^k$, where $m = deg(\psi)$.